# Check if product has been purchased

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, conditional-statements

Hi having 1 issue with my site I have no idea what to do for this part. I need to check if the product has been purchased. So if the user is logged in has purchased that item it displays something else compared to if they have not purchased that item.

Using this sample data

```
products
productID, title, runTime, imageLarge, classification
1, noah, 128 minutes, noahLarge.jpg, M
2, left behind, 105 minutes, leftBehindLarge.jpg, MA 15+
3, green lantern, 133 minutes, greenLantern.jpg, M

invoice
invoiceID, memberID, purchaseDate
1,11,1/10/2014
2,13,15/10/2014


productsinvoice
invoiceID, productID
1, 2
1, 3
2, 1
2, 2

members
memberID, username, pass, first name, last name
11, bob, fwofefef, bob, marley
13, prius, f334ff43f, eski, martey
```

The issue lies in my SQL query and this snippet of code here

```
$sql = "SELECT productID, title, price, imageSmall, imageLarge FROM products WHERE releaseDATE < NOW() ORDER BY releaseDate DESC LIMIT 0,4";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con)); //run the query
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
     if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
      {
      echo '
      <h4>$'. $row['price'] .'</h4>
      <p><input type="button" value="Add to Cart" onclick="addtocart(' .$row['productID'] . ')" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add to cart"/></p>';
      }
      else {
      echo '
      <a href="../pages/movieWatch.php?productID='.$row['productID'].'" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"> Stream</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" class="btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hdd"> Download</a>';
      }
```

}
So basically if the user bob has purchased productID 2, 3 I want it to display an option for those 2 products but the rest all still say add to cart and ignore the $_SESSION['user'] was just making sure the if condition works and it does.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should also select the memberID from invoice table.
So your query should be:

```
SELECT productID, title, price, imageSmall, imageLarge, memberID FROM products JOIN productsinvoice ON productsinvoice.productID=products.productID JOIN invoice ON productsinvoice.invoiceID=invoice.invoiceID WHERE releaseDATE < NOW() ORDER BY releaseDate DESC LIMIT 0,4;
```

second, assuming that you also set the memberID in your session variable, add another condition inside your if-statement:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
   if ($row['memberID'] != $_SESSION['user']['memberID']) {
      echo '
      <h4>$'. $row['price'] .'</h4>
      <p><input type="button" value="Add to Cart" onclick="addtocart(' .$row['productID'] . ')" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add to cart"/></p>';
   }
} else {
  echo '
  <a href="../pages/movieWatch.php?productID='.$row['productID'].'" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"> Stream</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" class="btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hdd"> Download</a>';
}
```